# Crashes with android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android, crash, android-xml, tic-tac-toe, inflate-exception

I want to make a tic tac toe game in android with java. I have two activity in my project. when I run my project I will receive a message ( **app is stopped** ) and the app is closed!

I test my app in Virtual device and Real device, I don't have any error in my project. just when Run is finished I get this error in my run window:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sina.dozbazi, PID: 31467
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sina.dozbazi/com.sina.dozbazi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.sina.dozbazi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.sina.dozbazi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070060
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2598)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:255)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:142)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1563)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1614)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.sina.dozbazi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

and this is my XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:onClick="go"
    android:text="New Game"
    app:backgroundTint="#0073FF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/design" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide your XML file? 
Stacktrace tells you `Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class ImageView`

Comment: Add this line into the ImageView : `android : weight = "1"`

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070060` => `@drawable/design` cannot be found, try rebuild your project

Comment: make sure you have `design` image in default drawable folder also not just in dpi folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml line no#49. Change the drawable or compress the drawable of **ImageView** because your it is too large to inflate.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I was able to solve my problem After a few weeks with your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want show large image in your app so you can add following attribute in manifests  file for that:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

so your app not crash

Answer (score 1):

Use app:src instead or srcCompat or use AppCompact Library or Androidx library